# PHP Search folder for files with specific suffix and extension

Tags: php

I'm looking to search in a folder for images starting with a specific suffix, I have this code, which works well but it get all images:

```
$foldertosearch = "images/temp/";

if (($countimages = glob($foldertosearch . "*.[jJ][pP]{[eE],}[gG]", GLOB_BRACE)) != false) { 
$numberofimages = count($countimages); 
} else {
$numberofimages = 0;    
}

if ($numberofimages > 0) {
foreach ( $countimages as $imagefile) {

    //Do whatever with each image

}
}
```

This work great, however, I need to look only for some images and ignore the rest... the images are like:

```
4-hello.jpg
4-image.jpg
4-hi.jpg
6-bestpicture.jpg
8-hiagain.jpg
```

So I would need to only use the ones a 4 or 6 in the beginning, or the ones the script is looking for... all images are named with a number and "-" in the beginning of every file. Although the number can go from 1 to 1000 or even more.

Who can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust the pattern you're using.

```
if (($countimages = glob($foldertosearch . "[46]-*.{jpg,jpeg,JPG,JPEG}", GLOB_BRACE)) != false) {
```

`[46]` will match a 4 or a 6

`-` will literally match -

`*` will match 0 or more characters

`.` will literally match .

`{jpg,jpeg,JPG,JPEG}` will match jpg, jpeg, JPG, or JPEG

[Glob Patterns](http://www.cowburn.info/2010/04/30/glob-patterns/)